# Quickpic Layout on Android

Tags: android, layout, gridview

I would like to have a similar UI rendering as QuickPic android app in my application which consist in displaying picture with a little checkbox on the top right of each image.

What would you recommend to do?

- A GridView layout + setup checkbox programmatically for each image?
- A Gallery Layout + setup checkboxes programmatically for each image?

I wanted to have some recommendations before starting the development.

PS: Each image will be loaded remotely using a lazy load mechanism.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exact solution that you are looking for: [Android custom image gallery with checkbox in grid to select multiple](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)

I am sure you gone through this example fully and understood the custom adapter the author has defined.

Comment: @FlorentValdelievre Proceed further in development...cheers :)